# empty terminal with multi lines

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal

I have problem with `terminal` .. I run a command but it took a time to be finish and it  printed a lot of lines in terminal but when I came back to first line by mouse I got blank and empty screen .. How can I make `terminal` save the lines exist ?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some bugs with your terminal emulator (`gnome-terminal` I assume), but if your goal is to read that data, you don't need to rely on terminal's scroll. You could always try a different terminal emulator, but all you need is to do something with that text.

1. We can redirect that stream of data to a file (`&>` instead of `>` will *capture* even error output):

   ```
   my_command_with_long_output > /path/to/file
   ```

   Then read it with some text editor of choice.
2. You can also redirect it directly to a pager like `less`:

   ```
   my_command_with_long_output | less
   ```

   and use `less`'s scrolling (<kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>/<kbd>u</kbd>).

The point is that the terminal emulator doesn't even need to be able to scroll for you to see long output.

Comment: thanks a lot for replying but what if i want to see the first line during run ?

Comment: There are so many options how to answer this, but I would suggest trying `tee` command. You would use it like `my_command | tee /path/to/file` and it basically redirects output to said file **as well as outputs it to stdout for you to read instantly**. You could combine it with more tools, Maybe you wanted to store it as whole for you to read with editor, but only see first line during run: `my_command | tee /path/to/file | head -n 1`.